Binary heap based priority queue implementation in C#
I made this Priority Queue implementation for C# since it doesn't support updating priorities in logarithmic time complexity. I did some tests and it seems that it's correct. However, I'm not sure whether the tests I did truly prove that it works properly. I would like to get it reviewed. Of course, any kind of optimization regarding time/space complexity would be appreciated, assuming that the code would work properly with it.
Here is the code I made supporting operations that I need.
public class MyPriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>
    where TElement : notnull 
{
    private readonly List<(TElement Element, TPriority Priority)> heap = new();
    private readonly Dictionary<TElement, int> itemIndices = new();

    public MyPriorityQueue() => Comparer = Comparer<TPriority>.Default;
    public MyPriorityQueue(IComparer<TPriority> comparer) => Comparer = comparer;

    public int Count => heap.Count;
    public IComparer<TPriority> Comparer { get; }

    public void Enqueue(TElement item, TPriority priority)
    {
        heap.Add((item, priority));
        itemIndices[item] = Count - 1;
        BubbleUp(Count - 1);
    }

    public void EnqueueOrUpdate(TElement item, TPriority priority)
    {
        if (itemIndices.TryGetValue(item, out var index))
        {
            heap[index] = (item, priority);
            BubbleUp(index);
            BubbleDown(index);
        }
        else
        {
            Enqueue(item, priority);
        }
    }

    public bool TryDequeue(out TElement element, out TPriority priority)
    {
        if (Count == 0)
        {
            (element, priority) = (default, default);
            return false;
        }

        var minItem = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap[^1];
        itemIndices[heap[0].Element] = 0;

        heap.RemoveAt(Count - 1);
        if (Count > 0)
        {
            BubbleDown(0);
        }
        
        (element, priority) = minItem;
        return true;
    }

    private void BubbleUp(int index)
    {
        while (index > 0)
        {
            var parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;
            if (Compare(index, parentIndex))
            {
                Swap(index, parentIndex);
                index = parentIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void BubbleDown(int index)
    {
        int smallestIndex;

        while (true)
        {
            var leftChildIndex = 2 * index + 1;
            var rightChildIndex = 2 * index + 2;
            smallestIndex = index;

            if (leftChildIndex < Count && Compare(leftChildIndex, smallestIndex))
            {
                smallestIndex = leftChildIndex;
            }

            if (rightChildIndex < Count && Compare(rightChildIndex, smallestIndex))
            {
                smallestIndex = rightChildIndex;
            }

            if (smallestIndex == index)
            {
                break;
            }

            Swap(index, smallestIndex);
            index = smallestIndex;
        }
    }

    private bool Compare(int leftIndex, int rightIndex) =>
        Comparer.Compare(heap[leftIndex].Priority, heap[rightIndex].Priority) < 0;

    private void Swap(int leftIndex, int rightIndex)
    {
        (heap[leftIndex], heap[rightIndex]) = (heap[rightIndex], heap[leftIndex]);

        itemIndices[heap[leftIndex].Element] = leftIndex;
        itemIndices[heap[rightIndex].Element] = rightIndex;
    }
}


Welcome to Code Review! I noticed in version 1 the final closing brace/bracket was not formatting with the rest of the code so I updated the formatting so code fences are used in order to have all code formatted in the same manner. Please check the indentation of the first and second lines. If something should be updated then it would be good to [edit] that before any answers come in.

Glad to be here! Thanks for reaching out. I just moved first curly brace to the next line and I think it all looks good now.

If this submission included an automated test suite, it would be easier to reason about its correctness and try out additional corner cases. Since no one has posted an Answer yet, there is still time to update the Question.

Do you host this anywhere? Maybe GitHub? I would have liked to see also the tests and demo program.

@coderodde I just added 1000000 random items with random priorities and checked whether they come out sorted at least 10 times

And no I don't host it anywhere

Advice I - where TPriority : notnull
I would add where TPriority : notnull to the class declaraction, since the priority keys are always required.
Note I
I like your hack:
BubbleUp(index);
BubbleDown(index);

At most one of the two above calls will actually bubble up or down. By the way, it is conventional to call BubbleX as SiftX.
Advice II - performance
You could squeeze some CPU cycles by relying on an array of heap nodes, each heap node containing the item, priority and the index of the item, instead of a List.
Note II - slight incorretness
If you run the following:
var q = new MyPriorityQueue<int, int>();

q.Enqueue(1, 1);
q.Enqueue(1, 1);
q.EnqueueOrUpdate(1, 0);
q.EnqueueOrUpdate(1, 2);

Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}.", q.Count);

bool b = q.TryDequeue(out int e, out int p);

Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}.", b, e, p);
Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}.", q.Count);

b = q.TryDequeue(out e, out p);

Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}.", b, e, p);
Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}.", q.Count);

you will get:
Size: 2.
True: 1, 1. <--- Should be "True: 1, 0."
Size: 1.
True: 1, 2.
Size: 0.

Advice III - alternative API
I suggest you rip an interface (call it, for example, PriorityQueue) since there are several priority queue data types: binary heap, \$d\$-ary heap, binomial heap, Fibonacci heap, pairing heap.
The interface in question is:
namespace CR.MyPriorityQueue
{
    internal interface PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>
    {
        void Enqueue(TElement element, TPriority priority);
        bool Dequeue(out TElement element, out TPriority priority);
    }
}

Above, if the element to enqueue does not appear in the queue, it is added. Otherwise, its priority is updated.
Summa summarum
All in all, I had the following rewrite in mind. I start with your rewrite:

namespace CR.PriorityQueues
{
    class MyPriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority> : PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>
    where TElement : notnull
    {
        private readonly List<(TElement Element, TPriority Priority)> heap = new();
        private readonly Dictionary<TElement, int> itemIndices = new();

        public MyPriorityQueue() => Comparer = Comparer<TPriority>.Default;
        public MyPriorityQueue(IComparer<TPriority> comparer) => Comparer = comparer;

        public int Count => heap.Count;
        public IComparer<TPriority> Comparer { get; }

        public void Enqueue(TElement item, TPriority priority)
        {
            if (itemIndices.TryGetValue(item, out int index))
            {
                heap[index] = (item, priority);
                BubbleUp(index);
                BubbleDown(index);
            }
            else
            {
                heap.Add((item, priority));
                itemIndices[item] = Count - 1;
                BubbleUp(Count - 1);
            }
        }

        public bool Dequeue(out TElement element, out TPriority priority)
        {
            if (Count == 0)
            {
                (element, priority) = (default, default);
                return false;
            }

            var minItem = heap[0];
            heap[0] = heap[^1];
            itemIndices[heap[0].Element] = 0;

            heap.RemoveAt(Count - 1);
            if (Count > 0)
            {
                BubbleDown(0);
            }

            (element, priority) = minItem;
            return true;
        }

        private void BubbleUp(int index)
        {
            while (index > 0)
            {
                var parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;
                if (Compare(index, parentIndex))
                {
                    Swap(index, parentIndex);
                    index = parentIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void BubbleDown(int index)
        {
            int smallestIndex;

            while (true)
            {
                var leftChildIndex = 2 * index + 1;
                var rightChildIndex = 2 * index + 2;
                smallestIndex = index;

                if (leftChildIndex < Count && Compare(leftChildIndex, smallestIndex))
                {
                    smallestIndex = leftChildIndex;
                }

                if (rightChildIndex < Count && Compare(rightChildIndex, smallestIndex))
                {
                    smallestIndex = rightChildIndex;
                }

                if (smallestIndex == index)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Swap(index, smallestIndex);
                index = smallestIndex;
            }
        }

        private bool Compare(int leftIndex, int rightIndex) =>
            Comparer.Compare(heap[leftIndex].Priority, heap[rightIndex].Priority) < 0;

        private void Swap(int leftIndex, int rightIndex)
        {
            (heap[leftIndex], heap[rightIndex]) = (heap[rightIndex], heap[leftIndex]);

            itemIndices[heap[leftIndex].Element] = leftIndex;
            itemIndices[heap[rightIndex].Element] = rightIndex;
        }
    }
}

Next, I will show your what I had in mind:
namespace CR.PriorityQueues
{
    class CoderoddeBinaryHeap<TElement, TPriority> : PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>
        where TElement : notnull
        where TPriority : notnull
    {
        private static readonly int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

        private class HeapNode<Element, Priority> where Element : notnull where Priority : notnull
        {
            public Element element;
            public Priority priority;
            public int index;

            public HeapNode(Element element, Priority priority)
            {
                this.element = element;
                this.priority = priority;
            }

            public string ToString()
            {
                return "[" + element.ToString() + " - " + priority.ToString() + ", index: " + index + "]";
            }
        }

        private int size;
        private HeapNode<TElement, TPriority>[] heapNodeArray =
            new HeapNode<TElement, TPriority>[INITIAL_CAPACITY];

        private readonly Dictionary<TElement, HeapNode<TElement, TPriority>> map = new();

        public IComparer<TPriority> Comparer { get; }

        public CoderoddeBinaryHeap()
        {
            Comparer = Comparer<TPriority>.Default;
        }

        public CoderoddeBinaryHeap(IComparer<TPriority> comparer)
        {
            Comparer = comparer;
        }

        public int Count => size;

        public void Enqueue(TElement item, TPriority priority)
        {
            if (map.TryGetValue(item, out var node))
            {
                node.priority = priority;
                SiftUp(node.index);
                SiftDown(node.index);
            }
            else
            {
                if (IsFull())
                {
                    ExtendHeapNodeArray();
                }

                HeapNode<TElement, TPriority> newNode = new HeapNode<TElement, TPriority>(item, priority);
                newNode.index = size;
                heapNodeArray[size] = newNode;
                size++;
                SiftUp(size - 1);
                map[item] = newNode;
            }
        }

        public bool Dequeue(out TElement element, out TPriority priority)
        {
            if (size == 0)
            {
                (element, priority) = (default, default);
                return false;
            }

            HeapNode<TElement, TPriority> node = heapNodeArray[0];
            size--;
            heapNodeArray[0] = heapNodeArray[size];
            node.index = 0;
            SiftDown(0);
            (element, priority) = (node.element, node.priority);
            heapNodeArray[size] = null;

            if (ShouldShrink())
            {
                ShrinkHeapNodeArray();
            }

            return true;
        }

        private void SiftUp(int index)
        {
            HeapNode<TElement, TPriority> node = heapNodeArray[index];
            TPriority priority = node.priority;

            while (index > 0)
            {
                int parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;
                HeapNode<TElement, TPriority> parentNode = heapNodeArray[parentIndex];

                if (Comparer.Compare(priority, parentNode.priority) < 0)
                {
                    heapNodeArray[index] = parentNode;
                    parentNode.index = index;
                    index = parentIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            heapNodeArray[index] = node;
            node.index = index;
        }
        private void SiftDown(int index)
        {
            HeapNode<TElement, TPriority> node = heapNodeArray[index];
            TPriority priority = node.priority;

            while (true)
            {
                int minimumChildIndex;
                int leftChildIndex = 2 * index + 1;

                if (leftChildIndex < size)
                {
                    minimumChildIndex = leftChildIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    heapNodeArray[index] = node;
                    node.index = index;
                    return;
                }

                int rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;

                if (rightChildIndex < size && Compare(rightChildIndex, leftChildIndex))
                {
                    minimumChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
                }

                if (Comparer.Compare(priority, heapNodeArray[minimumChildIndex].priority) > 0)
                {
                    heapNodeArray[index] = heapNodeArray[minimumChildIndex];
                    heapNodeArray[index].index = index;

                    index = minimumChildIndex;
                    leftChildIndex = index * 2 + 1;
                    rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    heapNodeArray[index] = node;
                    node.index = index;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsFull()
        {
            return size == heapNodeArray.Length;
        }

        private void ExtendHeapNodeArray()
        {
            HeapNode<TElement, TPriority>[] newHeapNodeArray =
            new HeapNode<TElement, TPriority>[heapNodeArray.Length * 2];
            Array.Copy(heapNodeArray, 0, newHeapNodeArray, 0, size);
            heapNodeArray = newHeapNodeArray;
        }

        private bool ShouldShrink()
        {
            return heapNodeArray.Length / 2 != INITIAL_CAPACITY &&
                4 * size <= heapNodeArray.Length;
        }

        private void ShrinkHeapNodeArray()
        {
            HeapNode<TElement, TPriority>[] newHeapNodeArray =
            new HeapNode<TElement, TPriority>[heapNodeArray.Length / 2];
            Array.Copy(heapNodeArray,
                       0,
                       newHeapNodeArray,
                       0,
                       newHeapNodeArray.Length);

            heapNodeArray = newHeapNodeArray;
        }

        private bool Compare(int leftIndex, int rightIndex) =>
            Comparer.Compare(heapNodeArray[leftIndex].priority,
                             heapNodeArray[rightIndex].priority) < 0;
    }
}

(The entire benchmark program is in my gist.)
Typical output
Seed = -264809311.
MyPriorityQueue`2.Enqueue() in 625 milliseconds.
MyPriorityQueue`2.TryDequeue() in 1941 milliseconds.
Total MyPriorityQueue`2 duration: 2566 milliseconds.

CoderoddeBinaryHeap`2.Enqueue() in 835 milliseconds.
CoderoddeBinaryHeap`2.TryDequeue() in 450 milliseconds.
Total CoderoddeBinaryHeap`2 duration: 1285 milliseconds.

Algorithms agree: True.

MyPriorityQueue`2 is sorted: True.
CoderoddeBinaryHeap`2 is sorted: True.

Hope that helps.

You can get even more performance when you make HeapNode a struct (x2 perf) and I think a 4-ary heap is even better than a binary heap. (.net PrioQueue uses 4-ary heap)
